# WPF Add items to observable collection and print. Returning object reference error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a simple app here that uses an observable collection and generates tabcontrol tabs per item. However when I try to add additional tabs it fails. I also noticed when i attempt to print the data in the collection, it appears i can not do that. I get the following error for both lines of code.

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property

```
InitializeComponent();
//ERRORS on both lines below
Console.WriteLine(ViewModel.TabItems);
ViewModel.AddContentItem();
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //ERRORS on both lines below
            Console.WriteLine(ViewModel.TabItems);
            ViewModel.AddContentItem();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:data="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="250">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <data:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems;

        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
        {
            get { return tabItems ?? (tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>()); }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        }

        public void AddContentItem()
        {
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        }
    }



    public class TabItem
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ObservableObject.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this instead

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var viewModel = (ViewModel) this.DataContext;

            Debug.WriteLine(viewModel.TabItems);
            viewModel.AddContentItem();
        }
    }
}
```

*Updated* thanks King King

Comment: `DataContext` is just an object so you need to explicitly cast it to `ViewModel`.